# Is there any way to convert a variable macro into 0 or 1 based on whether it is defined?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to define a macro which can take another macro as a argument and return 0 if it is not defined, returning 1 if it is

The preprocessor has an operator called `defined` which does exactly this, but it is only available in `#if` directives. I wonder if I can somehow expose this functionality outside of `#if`, such as in the middle of a line of C++ code.

Is this in general possible, and if so, how?

Comment: You have to know that the preprocessor treats any undefined macros as false. You can rely on that if all you really need is conditional compilation.

Comment: As far as I understood, you're trying to check if a macro is defined at runtime, but macros are expanded at preproccesing (before compiling), so it's not possible.

Comment: Actually, I want it at compile-time. The macros would be defined on command line at compile-time. I just do not want to add a new macro block for every variable that might be defined.

Comment: @merlin2011 You can't do that. (Fortunately? Unfortunately?)

Comment: @merlin2011 Have you looked into the ability to define values for macros on the command-line for your compiler (where you would then always specify the macros with explicit values of 0 or 1)? I am not sure if this would be easier, but not knowing your end goal or your compiler, this might suit your needs if you have not yet considered it.

Comment: The details are a little convoluted, but the purpose of this "conversion macro" is precisely so that macros which are NOT defined on the command line can be defaulted to 0 for the purpose of the actual C++ code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I understood you want something like below which is **impossible** unfortunately:

```
#define IS_DEFINED_MACRO(X) #ifdef(X) 1 #else 0 #endif  // IMPOSSIBlE!

int x = IS_DEFINED_MACRO(MACRO_TO_TEST);
```

The only possible way is

```
#ifdef MACRO_TO_TEST
   #define IT_IS_DEFINED 1
#else
   #define IT_IS_DEFINED 0
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I read your comment "is precisely so that macros which are NOT defined on the command line can be defaulted to 0 for the purpose of the actual C++ code".

One thing you can do is simply define a default value for each of the respective macros:

```
#ifndef WIBBLE
#define WIBBLE 0
#endif
```

And then when you compile, you can optionally pass `-DWIBBLE=100` to the compiler to override the default value.

Comment: That's adding 3 lines of code for each macro. I'm trying to avoid doing that because # of possible macros might be large.

Comment: @merlin2011: What many configure programs do is script the generation of a config.h file, so that the programmer does not need to type excessively.